# How can I get the new image id after editing an image in dropzone javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, dropzone

How can I get new image id after editing an image in dropzone javascript plugin

I use the following codes to edit the images of my products, but when I edit an image and send the image id, it sends the previous image id to edit the rest of the images.
Please help me, I need your help.

This code is in `foreach php` and is used for several images:

```
<label class="js-update-photo-product" data-action="change" data-photo-id="<?php echo $photo['id'] ?>">
     <i class="la la-refresh icon-md text-muted"></i>
</label>
```

And this modal is also out of `foreach`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_update_photo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalSizeXl" aria-hidden="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="photo_id" value="">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">تغییر تصویر
                    <span class="label label-xl label-light-primary label-inline">
                        number photo
                        (
                        <span id="number_photo"></span>
                        )
                    </span>
                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i aria-hidden="true" class="ki ki-close"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="dropzone dropzone-default dropzone-danger dz-clickable" id="update_photo_product">
                    <div class="dropzone-msg dz-message needsclick">
                        <i class="flaticon-upload display2 mb-1"></i>
                        <h3 class="dropzone-msg-title">
                             To upload, drag and drop your image to this area. You can also click.
                        </h3>
                        <span class="dropzone-msg-desc">
                             To upload, drag and drop your image to this area. You can also click.
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-danger font-weight-bold" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my `JavaScript code`:
My problem is in the field of `sending photo_id in dropzone`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'label.js-update-photo-product', function (event){
    const photo_id = $(this).data('photo-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'requests/AjaxRequest.php',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            photo_id: photo_id,
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response['data'])
            if (response.status === 200){
                $("#number_photo").html(response['data']['sort'])
                $("input[name=photo_id]").val(response['data']['id'])
                $('#modal_update_photo').modal('show');
                $('#update_photo_product').dropzone({
                    url: "/requests/PhotoProductRequest.php",
                    paramName:"photo_product",
                    maxFiles: 1,
                    maxFilesize: 1,
                    addRemoveLinks: false,
                    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                    params:{
                        photo_id: $("input[name=photo_id]").val(),
                    },
                    accept: function (file, done){
                        done();
                    },
                    error: function (file, resp) {

                        let response = JSON.parse(resp);

                        if (file.previewElement) {
                            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                            if (typeof response !== "string" && response.message) {
                                response = response.message;
                            }
                            for (let node of file.previewElement.querySelectorAll(
                                "[data-dz-errormessage]"
                            )) {
                                node.textContent = response;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
})
```